# R tidytext sentiment analysis- how to use the drop parameter

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis, tidytext

I recently asked a question about entries that are omitted after a sentiment analysis. The tweets that I analyse don't always contain words that are in the lexicon. I would like to know which ones can't be translated. So I would like to keep these even if zero words were scored. In my previous question, the drop parameter was given as a solution. However, I think I might be doing it wrong or missing something. This is my first time working with these techniques.

The following function takes a data frame and gives a new one in return, containing the amount of positive and negative words along with the sentiment.

**The input** (with one text in Dutch on purpose so it can't be scored)

```
id <- c(1, 2, 3)
date <- c("12-05-2021", "12-06-2021", "12-07-2021")
text <- c("Dit is tekst in het Nederlands", "I,m so happy that websites like this exsist", "This icecream tastes terrible. It made me upset")

df <- data.frame(id, date, text)
```

What i want as output is:

```
sentiment     positive     negative
0             0            0
2             2            0
-2            0            2
```

But my function gives me something else:

```
sentimentAnalysis <- function(tweetData){
  
  sentimentDataframe <- data.frame()
  
  for(row in 1:nrow(tweetData)){
    
    tekst <- as.character(tweetData[row, "text"])
    
    positive <- 0
    negative <- 0
    
    tokens <- tibble(text = tekst) %>% unnest_tokens(word, text, drop = FALSE)
    
    sentiment <- tokens %>%
      inner_join(get_sentiments("bing")) %>% 
      count(sentiment) %>% 
      spread(sentiment, n, fill = 0) %>% 
      mutate(sentiment = positive - negative)
    
    
    sentimentDataframe <- bind_rows(sentimentDataframe, sentiment)
  }
  
  sentimentDataframe[is.na(sentimentDataframe)] <- 0
  return(sentimentDataframe)
  
}
```

This still returns a data frame with the unscored texts missing. As you can see, the first text is omitted:

```
sentiment     positive     negative
2             2            0
-2            0            2
```

Comment: @RonakShah I have added the requested info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no rows returned after the join you can return a tibble with all 0 values. We can use an `if` condition to check this.

In cases when there is only positive or negative sentiment in a sentence, `complete` would create another row with opposite sentiment and assign it the value 0. Also replaced `spread` with `pivot_wider` since `spread` is now superseded.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)

map_df(df$text, ~{
  tibble(text = .x) %>% 
    unnest_tokens(word, text, drop = FALSE) %>%
    inner_join(get_sentiments("bing")) -> tmp
  if(nrow(tmp) == 0) tibble(sentiment = 0, positive = 0, negative = 0)
  else {
  tmp %>%
    count(sentiment) %>% 
    complete(sentiment = c('positive', 'negative'), fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = sentiment, values_from = n, values_fill = 0) %>% 
    mutate(sentiment = positive - negative)
  }
}) -> res

res
#  sentiment positive negative
#      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#1         0        0        0
#2         2        2        0
#3        -2        0        2
```

Comment: This did the trick. Thank you very much for the help :)